# How do I enable the SSE/SSE2 instruction set in Visual Studio 2008 (using CMake)?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cmake

In Visual Studio 2005 I went in:

*View --> Property Pages --> C/C++ --> Code Generation --> Enable Enhanced Instruction Set*

But in Visual Studio 2008?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you're looking for SSE/SSE2: `Project > Properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Code Generation > Enable Enhanced Instruction Set`, or append `/arch:SSE` (or `/arch:SSE2`) in `Command Line > Additional Options`.

You need to have a native project, and at least one .cpp file added to access this, though.

Comment: Thank you so much! It's not a native project, but I create it with CMake.

Comment: If you regenerate the project files using CMake the settings will not be stored when using this approach. See my answer for details on a permanent fix...

Comment: @CatPlusPlus : Under`Project > Properties > Configuration Properties`I only have`configuration`

Answer (score 14):

Using CMake you could add the following to CMakeLists.txt:

```
IF(MSVC)
   ADD_DEFINITIONS(/arch:SSE)
ENDIF(MSVC)
```

or `/arch:SSE2`.

Comment: `warning: D9002 : ignoring unknown option '/arch:SSE2'`

Comment: @mchiasson: You will see this message if you try to enable `/arch:SSE2` option while building `x64` code. This basically tells you that you don't need it. `SSE`/`SSE2` is used by [default in `x64` builds](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1067630/670017).

Answer (score 1):

It is Project->Properties... (same path as above)

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I tried but in Project --> Properties I have:

- Common Properties
   + Startup Project
   + Project Dependencies
   + Debug Source Files
- Configuration Properties
   + Configuration

I don't find any option for the instruction set.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using inline assembler `__asm { .... }` you don't need to enable it.

But if you enable SSE you have to be careful. It may be that the code is slower than normal FPU code.