# Microsoft C++ compiler: how to disable auto-vectorization with /O2?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vectorization, compiler-optimization

How to disable auto-vectorization (SSE2), globally or for a specific `for` loop, without reverting to /Od in MSVS 2010?

I've tried all 3 possible options for `Enable Enhanced Instruction Set`, including "Not set", to no avail.

P. S. Curiously, even /Od doesn't help.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Why do I want to disable vectorization? For 2 reasons: to assess performance boost from using SSE2, and to allow for consistent and meaningful performance comparison with machines that do not have SSE.

Comment: Perhaps the following might be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1480916/how-do-i-enable-the-sse-sse2-instruction-set-in-visual-studio-2008-using-cmake

Comment: That makes tons of sense. Thanks for satisfying my curiosity. I wish I could reciprocate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a specific loop, you can add a pragma:

```
#pragma loop(no_vector)
```

This is actually [documented on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh923901.aspx) (although I only found it there after I learned about it..)

If you don't like to add a pragma, you can choose to compile with `/favor:ATOM`. That is a bit of hack, but it will allow you to disable auto-vectorization, without touching the source, and still optimize for speed otherwise.

Alternatively there are the two optimization strategies `/O1` "optimize size" and `/Os` "favor small code". Auto-vectorization generates substantially more code, so if you optimize for size, auto-vectorization is disabled.

I learned all this recently from by reading the [auto-vectorization cookbook](http://blogs.msdn.com/cfs-file.ashx/__key/communityserver-blogs-components-weblogfiles/00-00-01-04-99/3007.Auto_2D00_Vectorizer_2D00_08_2D00_Cookbook.pdf). See the last line of the section "Rules for the loop body".

Disclaimer: I am not actually using the VS2012 compiler yet (need to support Win XP), so I haven't tested this. Also, the compiler switches might work differently in 2013 or later.

Comment: Thanks for the link! BTW, have you seen there's a special vc11 runtime for XP? I believe that's how you can use 2012 compiler and runtime with XP.

Answer (score 2):

You could isolate your `for` loop in a separated function and try to use [`#pragma optimize`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chh3fb0k%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for it:

```
// Disable all optimizations
#pragma optimize("", off)

// your function here

// Enable them back
#pragma optimize("", on)
```

... but this should have the same effect of `/Od` just on that particular function, so it may not help.

If you are compiling for x86 (and not x86_64, where it has no effect) you could also disable the SSE2 instruction set as a whole (removing the [`/arch:SSE2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) option). Sadly, its granularity is limited to a whole source file.

Comment: Thanks, that ought to work - vectorization in /Od happens only in x64 (why?), but that's not exactly what I want since loop counter isn't even locked in a register in /Od. Performance impact will not only be due to vectorization.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the undocumented option- `/d2Qvec-` with the latest VS2022.

Answer (score 0):

Try making sure that the [/arch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t5yh4fd.aspx) compiler option is not set.

Answer (score 0):

Which compiler? AFAIK,  VS will implement auto-vectorization starting from  version 11. VS uses SSE instructions for floating-point, but it doesn't mean that it actually vectorizes loops.

Comment: VC 2010. Do you mean I am misinterpreting the term "vectorization"?